# PHP / MySQL Form

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTMl>
<html>
<body>
<?php
try { 
    $dbhandle = new PDO('mysql:host=dragon.kent.ac.uk;dbname=co323','user','pass');
} catch (PDOExeption $e) {
die('Error Connecting to Database: ' . $e->getMessage());
}


$driver = 'SELECT forename, surname, d.nationality, name FROM Drivers d JOIN Teams t ON d.id = t.id';
$query = $dbhandle->prepare($driver);

if ($query->execute() === FALSE ) {
die('Error Running Query: ' . implode($query->errorInfo(), ' '));
}

$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Forename</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Nationality</th>
    <th>Team</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['forename']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['nationality']; ?><td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<form action="task3a.php" method="GET">
    <select name=""driver>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
        <option value="</php echo $row ["id"];"?>" > <?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've had a go but its not completely working and I'm not sure why? I've added the form and it displays but not correctly :) I had to make a new question because it wouldn't let me post a reply :)

Comment: *How* does it not work? And did you notice the double-quotes misplaced around "driver" in the <select> tag near the bottom?

Comment: Your HTML markup looks broken, with the `<form>` nested inside the `<table>` but not in a `<tr><td>`.  Should the `<form>` come _after_ the closing `</table>`?

Comment: Also `value="</php echo $row ["id"];"?>"` needs to be `value="<?php echo $row ["id"]; ?>"` there's a `/` instead of `?` and an extra `"`

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do when starting out is to get good error handling / debugging tools in place that will help you catch syntax errors immediately, even point to specific line numbers in your code.

PHP has a setting that can be turned on:

```
ini_set("display_errors",true);
```

The W3C has a validator that will automatically detect errors in your html (you can view source / paste your html source into this service)

http://validator.w3.org/

Also, learning to get comfortable using your browser's dev tools (Firebug, chrome dev tools, etc) will save you major time in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

Your `value="</php`

should be `value="<?php`

Comment: And `echo $row ["id"];"?>` must be `echo $row["id"]; ?>`

Comment: Okay so I have,   <form action='task3a.php' method='GET'>
    <select name='driver'>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
    <option value=<?/php echo $row['id'];?> > <?php echo $row['name']; ?>     </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

Comment: almost correct, you should remove the slash after the ? in <?php.. something like this http://paste2.org/bXgvv9Oh

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not a bad start here are a few issues

As someone else pointed out your  is inside your  close your table tag and then start the form, you also didn't close your form off

so the end of you file should look like this

```
</table>
<form action="task3a.php" method="GET">
    <select name=""driver>
    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row ["id"];?>" > <?php echo $row["name"]; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You have mistyped your opening php tag in the `<option>` value attribute, this will not work.

Also you don't select an id feild in your sql, so you will need to do that, add `d.id` to your select statement

Finally I would check that $row['name'] is what you want for your select value, I think it might be a combination of firstname and lastname, it's hard to tell because your earlier query isn't specific.

```
$driver = 'SELECT forename, surname, d.nationality, name FROM Drivers d JOIN Teams t ON d.id = t.id';
```

In general it is good practice to use the tables as reference when selecting joins, you select d.nationality (I know that this is from your drivers table but none of the others are prefixed by a table (either d or t based on your AS statements)